# DOORS - Traceability Column

Tags: ibm-doors

I need to add a traceability column in DOORS that can show results from three different objects.

My module has two columns used as the reference columns: BPMN Object Type, and BPMN Object text.
The three BPMN Object types are Data Objects, Activities, and Events.
There are three modules, already setup, that have details for each of these respectively.
The BPMN Object text exists both in the source module, and the target module, with the column I need to bring into the source module, the Element Description, existing in the target module.
I can create the DXL traceability column to pull in each, but they are pulled into three separate columns.

Here is the DXL from a working example, created by one of my predecessors (NOTE: this was auto-generated by the Traceability Wizard in DOORS):

```
    // DXL generated by DOORS traceability wizard on 14 July 2015.
    // Wizard version 2.0, DOORS version 9.5.2.1
    pragma runLim, 0
    void showOut(Object o, int depth) {
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    //Auto Translated:     Item linkModItem = itemFromID("446ca74a57b60977-00031da0")
    //Auto Translated:     Item linkModItem = itemFromID("446ca74a57b60977-00031f80")
    Item linkModItem = itemFromID("446ca74a57b60977-00032080")
    if (null linkModItem) {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Link module not found>>")
    } else if (type(linkModItem) != "Link") {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Invalid link module index for this database>>")
    } else {
        string linkModName = fullName(linkModItem)
        for l in all(o->linkModName) do {
            otherVersion = targetVersion l
            otherMod = module(otherVersion)
            if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
            othero = target l
            if (null othero) {
                load(otherVersion,false)
            }
            othero = target l
            if (null othero) continue
            if (isDeleted othero) continue
            doneOne = true
            if (depth == 1) {
                disp = ""
                s = name(otherMod)
                if (isBaseline(otherVersion)) {
                    s = s " [" versionString(otherVersion) "]"
                }

                s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Element Description", true)
                disp = disp  s
                displayRich("\\pard " disp)
            }
        }
    }
}
showOut(obj,1)
```

I need the contents of the traceability column to display the Element Description for the BPMN Object Text, based on the BPMN Object Type.

Comment: *Clarification* - I need to add a traceability column in DOORS that can show results from three different Modules.

Comment: The solution depends on your setup. Do you use different Link modules for links to Data Objects, Activities and Events? (you should, since a link to a data object has a different meaning than a link to an event)

Comment: There are 3 link modules, to three different formal modules (Events, Activities, Data Objects).

Comment: then the solution below should work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the three lines pointing to different `linkModItem`s mean links to your three different module types. In this case, you need to create a loop over all `linkModItem`s, and for each link module execute the lines `Item linkModItem =...` and following.

Something like this should work:

```
string linkModuleIDs[] = {"446ca74a57b60977-00031da0", "446ca74a57b60977-00031f80", "446ca74a57b60977-00032080"}
int i
for (i=0 ; i < sizeof linkModuleIDs ; i++) {
  Item linkModItem = itemFromID(linkModuleIDs[i])
  if (null linkModItem) .... the rest like above
}
```

Comment: I was able to take a variation of your suggested solution and make it work with my current traceability columns:

Answer (score 0):

```
// DXL generated by DOORS traceability wizard on 16 September 2019.
// Wizard version 2.0, DOORS version 9.6.1.11
pragma runLim, 0
string limitModules[] = {"446ca74a57b60977-0002ac00", "446ca74a57b60977-000320a0", "446ca74a57b60977-0002ac02"}
void showOut(Object o, int depth) {
int i
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    Item linkModItem = itemFromID("446ca74a57b60977-00020b09")
for (i=0 ; i < sizeof limitModules ; i++) {
    if (null linkModItem) {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Link module not found>>")
    } else if (type(linkModItem) != "Link") {
        displayRich("\\pard " "<<Invalid link module index for this database>>")
    } else {
        string linkModName = fullName(linkModItem)
        for l in all(o->linkModName) do {
            otherVersion = targetVersion l
            otherMod = module(otherVersion)
            if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
            if (!equal(getItem otherMod, (itemFromID limitModules[i]))) continue
            othero = target l
            if (null othero) {
                load(otherVersion,false)
            }
            othero = target l
            if (null othero) continue
            if (isDeleted othero) continue
            doneOne = true
            if (depth == 1) {
                s = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Element Description", true)
                if (s == "") 
                displayRich("\\pard " " ")
                else
                displayRich("\\pard " s)
            }
        }
    }
}
}
showOut(obj,1)
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question, or did you mean to edit the question?